# What is protocol and host combined called?

Tags: http, url, uri, specifications

According to spec and semantics is protocol and host combined: `https://example.com` still called a host, or is this called a URL, URI, or something else?

Also, is *(https)* called protocol or scheme? [NGINX uses scheme](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html), but I don't see any reference to that origin.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Actually, it's all on wiki...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Relationship_between_URIs.2C_URLs.2C_and_URNs

The name you are looking for is URL. URI is a global name for resource identifiers, and URL is a specific type of URI used in web. 
And, according to the papers, you should use scheme, not host:
https://www.w3.org/TR/uri-clarification/#uri-schemes

Comment: Thanks. Assume you meant "you should use scheme, not protocol"?

Comment: "Scheme" is a term straight out of the [URI RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3.1), btw.

Answer (score 62):

I think the term you may really be looking for is ***origin***, as in [RFC 6454](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-5).

An origin isn’t just scheme+host, but scheme+host+port, and URLs like `https://example.com` aren’t actually just scheme+host — because they express a (default) port too:  443, the default TLS port — just as in `http://example.com` there’s a built-in expression that the port is 80.

I’m not sure what the context was for the original question here, but I know a common case that would normally motivate somebody to want to know what a combination of scheme+host is called is the case where you want to compare two URLs that either have the same host but different schemes, like  `https://example.com` and `http://example.com`, or that have the same scheme and host but different ports, like `http://example.com` and `http://example.com:8888`. And consideration of comparing URLs that way will eventually take you to thinking of them in terms of the ["same origin" policy](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6454#section-3) that the entire Web security model is based on.

Answer (score 18):

IMHO, origin is not the correct term, since origin refers to "where the communication comes from". But it can also be a destination.
Therefore, I think Base URL is the best-fitting term for protocol+host+port. See e.g. https://www.techopedia.com/definition/4858/base-url .

Answer (score 4):

(The following is according to the URI standard [STD 66](http://tools.ietf.org/html/std66), which currently maps to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986).)

An absolute URI with an authority (e.g., a domain name, or an IP address) [must](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3) consist of (in that order)

1. the [`scheme` component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1),
2. `:`,
3. `//`,
4. the [`authority` component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2), and
5. the [`path` component](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) (→ `path-abempty`).

So according to these rules, `https://example.com` is

- either a valid URI (with an empty path),
- or not yet a valid URI (because it misses the path, which could either be empty or start with `/`).

(But unless you find this URI in a specific context, one would of course assume that it’s a URI with an empty path.)

However, the HTTP specification RFC 2616 defines [scheme-specific rules for HTTP URIs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.2.2): if the URI is used as *Request-URI* ([see definition](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-5.1.2)), and the URI’s `abs_path` is empty, it must be given as `/` (i.e., `https://example.com/`).

Neither the URI standard nor the HTTP standard define a term that would only describe the combination of the `scheme` and the `authority` components.

Answer (score 1):

If you are ok with including the port part in the terminology, javascript parses that part of the url and puts it in the `origin` property.

```js
const { origin } = new URL(`https://stackoverflow.com:4200/questions/37232382/what-is-protocol-and-host-combined-called`);
console.log(origin) // Outputs: 'https://stackoverflow.com:4200'
```

Although it seems to omit the port too if it is something familiar like 443

```js
const { origin } = new URL(`https://stackoverflow.com:443/questions/37232382/what-is-protocol-and-host-combined-called`);
console.log(origin) // Outputs: 'https://stackoverflow.com'
```